# Why should we use different versions of Ethereum Wallet?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, voting

In a recent [Griff Green article](https://blog.slock.it/how-to-create-gorgeous-proposals-81eb3f606226#.5lc65toar) you can read to use either version 0.6.2 or 0.7.4 of Ethereum Wallet to vote and to create a proposal.

It's very confusing...

From the blog post:

> [...]create a test Proposal using the 0.6.2 version of the Ethereum
>   Wallet[...]create a proposal using the 0.6.2 version of the Ethereum
>   Wallet[...]how to turn the 0.7.4 version of the Ethereum Wallet into
>   Mist , how to vote with the 0.6.2 version of the Ethereum Wallet

So why don't we only use 0.7.4 for creating the contract and for voting ? The article seems to tell us to switch between versions to create and to vote.

In the end, what I understand is that you can't create a proposal with 0.7.4 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can create and vote on proposals in the 0.6.2 wallet, it is just that: a wallet.

The 0.7.4 release can be used in "Mist mode," in which it essentially functions as a full browser with a built in ethereum node. 
The Mist browser lets you view markdown and images associated with proposals.

I don't think the article is saying that you should switch between versions, since 0.7.x does everything the 0.6.x versions can do, it is simply pointing the reader to articles with instructions on how to vote in 0.6.2, since 0.7.4 hasn't been out long enough for people to write instructions on how to vote.

Answer (score 4):

**Reason: a functional Ethereum Browser!**
There was a bug in the 0.7.x releases that affected the `--mode mist` version of the Mist Wallet, which is the Mist Browser.

[The issue was solved in 0.7.4](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/pull/548).

Comment: Ok, so why don't only use 0.7.4 for creating the contract and fore voting ? The article seems to tell us to switch between versions to create and to vote. What I understand is that you can't create a proposal with 0.7.4 version. Updated my question by the way.